# Filter Firebase Realtime Database data based on authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database as the datastore for an Android app, and right now I'm trying to implement some basic filtering based on user permissions.

Here's my database:

```
{
    "admins" : { 
        `user1hash` : true
    },
    "clients" : {
        "client1hash" : {
            "owner": "user1hash",
            "name" : "Client 1"
        },
        "client2hash" : {
            "owner": "user1hash",
            "name" : "Client 2"
        },
        "client3hash" : {
            "owner": "user2hash",
            "name" : "Client 3"
        }
    }
}
```

I followed the examples in the **Query-based Rules** section here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data and defined my rules like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "clients": {
      ".indexOn": "owner",
        ".read": "auth.uid != null && (root.child('admins/' + auth.uid).val() == true || query.orderByChild == 'owner' && query.equalTo == auth.uid)",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null",
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['owner']) && newData.child('owner').val() == auth.uid"
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my client code (Android):

```
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        String authUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference clientsDatabase = database.getReference("clients").orderByChild("owner").equalTo(authUser).getRef();
        clientsDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // handle success
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // handle error
            }
        });
```

So basically I just want to be able to fetch all clients, but filter the results according to the access rules of the current user. Access rules are pretty simple, an user can only see the clients where he is the `owner`, except for admin users who can see all clients. For example if this was run by user1 which is an admin he should see all three clients, but if this is run by user2 which is a regular user he should only see client 3.

This implementation is working for admins, but I get a permissions error for regular users.

I tried the rules simulator in Firebase console, but it doesn't provide any documentation on how to use queries. Anyway I tried adding the query as a regular URL query string like `/clients?orderByChild=owner&equalTo=user2hash`, but this returns an empty error on the simulator with no description of the cause. The error I'm getting on the Android side doesn't have any description either, just a generic permissions error.

Comment: `.orderByChild(".owner")` looks like a typo, and should be `.orderByChild("owner")` (without the `.`).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your reply, you're correct, that's a typo, I'll update my question. Still getting the same error after fixing this. Also note that I'm getting a generic permissions error in the rules simulator in firebase console too. I haven't been able to find any logs on the firebase console or any other hints about the underlying error.

Comment: I don't think the simulator in the console can do anything like queries. It's mostly useful for testing straightforward reads or writes. But if you're trying to simulate a basic read or write, add a screenshots of the JSON + path + data + auth state to the question so we know what you're doing there. In general though, it's best to focus on one problem in a question. Too many variables make it hard to follow.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for the reply. You're right, looks like the simulator can't do queries, anyway that's not relevant to my problem and I've also tested on the app with same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this statement:

```
DatabaseReference clientsDatabase = 
    database.getReference("clients")
            .orderByChild("owner")
            .equalTo(authUser)
            .getRef();
```

Specifically that last line `getRef()`, which throws everything away that you've done to build the query. The above statement leaves `clientsDatabase` exactly the same as:

```
DatabaseReference clientsDatabase = database.getReference("clients");
```

Which explains quite well why the statement fails.

You need to keep the `Query` that you get back and attach your listener on that:

```
DatabaseReference clientsDatabase = database.getReference("clients");
Query query = clientsDatabase.orderByChild("owner").equalTo(authUser);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { ...
```

Comment: Oh, this makes sense! The documentation for the **Query-based Rules** only has examples for JavaScript, and I haven't used queries before so I didn't notice that. I'll test it and let you know how this works. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You were right, that was it! Thanks a lot man, I really appreciate your help!